# How to measure Java GC Stop The World time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I know we can get the GC duration from the GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo object, but the duration there seems to be the entire duration (e.g., I found 5+ seconds once) which could be much larger than the actual stop the world pause (typically less than 1 seconds from my experience), is there anyway we can get the actual stop the world pause duration? Either somehow calculated from the available sources (I do not think GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo provide us with those details? but I could be wrong) or any other ways? I know jstat tool prints the FGCT column which seems to be reflecting exactly the stop the world pause time, how do they do that then? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the `GcInfo` object held by the bean say? What you are looking for is data related to "full" collections, as partial collections will not stop the world, and full collections _will_ stop the world for pretty much that whole collection duration.

Comment: GcInfo only has start time, end time since JVM starts and the duration,  and the memory usage of different memory pools (e.g., Eden Space), what I actually want to achieve is to get the Stop The World pause time by monitoring the JVM directly (like using a running service), not monitoring say the JVM log output, it would be more desirable if we can directly get or calculated somehow from the data exposed by JVM (e.g., the GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo ),

Comment: Oracle docs say that GcInfo.getDuration() "Returns the elapsed time of this GC in milliseconds." If this GC is a full collection, it has stopped the world for pretty much this entire time. One hopes the other properties on the parent object let you query what sort of GC this is.

Answer (score 2):

To get all STW pauses in the VM log output you need to pass the following two options. This includes non-GC safepoints.

`-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1`

Alternatively there's `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime`

Keep in mind that non-safepoint things can induce pauses too (e.g. the kernel's thread scheduler). There's [jHiccup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15350585/1362755) to measure those.

Comment: how about programmatic access to that pause time? with GCNotificationInfos you can monitor from within the application and do some alerting/reporting if needed. Is there a way to acheive programmatic access? (without nasty hacks like parsing stdin)

Comment: @vach not that I am aware of. just monitor the time an application is responsive instead. in the end a safepoint is just yet another incomplete approximation for things most people are actually concerned about. that's what jhiccup does anyway.